# Transactions and smart contracts during reorganization

Tags: transactions, contract-design, chain-reorganization

I learned from this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62665/what-is-the-change-in-smart-contract-when-the-chain-reorganizations) that transactions will be reverted and rollback after chain reorganization. But after a transaction is reverted, will the sender needs to resend this transaction? Or this transaction will automatically go into transactions pool and wait to be included in a new block?

When it comes to smart contracts, how smart contracts deal with this kind of revert/rollback problems due to chain reorganization?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer...

> When it comes to smart contracts, how smart contracts deal with this kind of revert/rollback problems due to chain reorganization?

The smart contract itself doesn't need to deal with anything: it will be as though the transaction never happened, and no state changes occurred.

What might need to be dealt with are any changes that happen off-chain in response to the transaction. e.g. If your website/front-end has taken an action, such as a redirect, in response to the transaction completing, but then that transaction gets invalidated, then you'll need to ensure the front-end changes are reverted.

To do this, most people wait for a certain number of confirmations* before taking any subsequent actions.

[*I think the generally accepted number is 6, but the following question and its answers would imply that ephemeral chain forks above length 2 are extremely unlikely, so 6 might be overkill: [Distribution of chain-reorganization events?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/distribution-of-chain-reorganization-events/73020#73020) ]