# Detect orphant or uncle block

Tags: uncle-blocks, data-validity

At a specificed time, I got a block from physical node with number `10074305` and it returned hash `0xdd30541695c4e574839d2356a01ff19e68c8c90c180b8955623c5e0b4b7e864a` (#0), then after a period time, this hash was changed to `0x6dcb187acb68646a4238f645650c9ee356746193b8dc06bc9df46f2dfedc2777` (#1). I have researched and it is called by `re-organization chain` ([ref](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19389/chain-reorganization-tx-hash-change/19393#19393)), but I don't know what type block #0? 
At the moment, block #0 is still available on network by using `eth_getBlockByHash` to check (not available on public explorer ex etherscan,...), but in block #1 I don't see any `uncles []`. All of 17 transactions from #0 are valid transactions, but 2 of them is belong to next block `10074306`. So, please help me to explain few questions: 
+ Which type of block #0? 
+ If it is `re-organization chain` case, transactions may be rollbacked, if I have recorded a transaction, and unluckily it is rollbacked, what shall I do? I think at this time I check transaction receipt, it is still valid, so after 12 next block passed, I have a ghost (not exist) transaction? 
Thanks so much for helping and best regards.

Here are responses (transaction hashes are removed for saving space):

## 0:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": {
        "difficulty": "0x8054b1954c717",
        "extraData": "0x505059452d65746865726d696e652d6575312d31",
        "gasLimit": "0x989680",
        "gasUsed": "0x985f5e",
        "hash": "0xdd30541695c4e574839d2356a01ff19e68c8c90c180b8955623c5e0b4b7e864a",
        "logsBloom": "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",
        "miner": "0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8",
        "mixHash": "0x292cbe5354bc1654e08055b1e9991f10b8b7dbed03c97ac24b881978744536e2",
        "nonce": "0x6253a4a314383e07",
        "number": "0x99b8c1",
        "parentHash": "0xb64ff03f8a72f1931622fde9172a440d9fe82b6b1e14cdc9f76689fcd591205f",
        "receiptsRoot": "0x60d49574be7f70a8cfc128a65c579fd7db2eee2640f38817e264909fdf4ece5a",
        "sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
        "size": "0x100f4",
        "stateRoot": "0xf7e12beab13dada068e802f300870121cecbf982f63ce906799bd1ba359f44ce",
        "timestamp": "0x5ebf4949",
        "totalDifficulty": "0x3452c6dc17cbf4da827",
        "transactions": [17txs],
        "transactionsRoot": "0x44d21304539fff5005c1d3db41392e30f64cc6504d84f3f479fbaf0b8ac143a4",
        "uncles": []
    }
}
```

## 1:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": {
        "difficulty": "0x8054b1954c717",
        "extraData": "0x505059452d65746865726d696e652d6575312d34",
        "gasLimit": "0x989680",
        "gasUsed": "0x9854f8",
        "hash": "0x6dcb187acb68646a4238f645650c9ee356746193b8dc06bc9df46f2dfedc2777",
        "logsBloom": "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",
        "miner": "0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8",
        "mixHash": "0x0f453fe6267e7e432bfe3c4bb19973dfe92b894ffab44fe5cce408ce25c48a5a",
        "nonce": "0xcde83c5800562c35",
        "number": "0x99b8c1",
        "parentHash": "0xb64ff03f8a72f1931622fde9172a440d9fe82b6b1e14cdc9f76689fcd591205f",
        "receiptsRoot": "0xe0ba91bfd24347ac359d8c2207b8b2d871d7bcfd9175ddaa6e6330ad3c57f399",
        "sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
        "size": "0x10956",
        "stateRoot": "0xc7f8bbb8d2957d6840fafbae1efbf28d101a9cc968c7d4c63097999ae6cd99a5",
        "timestamp": "0x5ebf4949",
        "totalDifficulty": "0x3452c6dc17cbf4da827",
        "transactions": [15txs],
        "transactionsRoot": "0xaa6ac619660443054e9eb72b088fdd9b4e9a380c7b5dd53c796fa50737b127d4",
        "uncles": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block (#0) doesn't have a name. It may appear as an uncle in a future block but not necessarily.

Transaction from block (#0) should be considered as pending. They might still appear in a future block. The receipt should have a null block if they are still pending or a new block hash if they were mined.

If transactions are still pending after some time you may want to consider replacing it, by re-sending them with the same nonce and a higher gas price.

Even if you try replacing a pending transaction it might happen that the first one is mined and the old one is discarded.

Comment: You mean block #0 does not have a valid number? But at that time I call `eth_blockNumber`, it was returned block #0 and I also checked receipt at there, that means all of those transactions are valid, the process would continue to next block. After a period time, block #0 was removed and replaced by #1, but my reading process is passed block no `10074305` and I could not find a transaction from block #1 in my reading process.

Comment: `Transaction from block (#0) should be considered as pending. They might still appear in a future block`, I agree with your point but 1 of transactions from block #1 is does not appear in my log and I don't know why, may you explain it? I just think I must re-read block #0 is the best option, donesn't it? Thanks for your response and have a good day.

Comment: @mmo2112 In a PoW blockchain at any moment a block can be replaced by another with a larger proof of work. When a block is replaced all of its transactions return to the pending pool and can be mined in a new block. Once a transaction arrives to the pending pool it can be replaced or dropped. In Ethereum short reorgs happen every day but longer reorgs are unlikely, but they are still possible.

Comment: thanks for your explain so much and have a nice day.