# Listen for Reorganized Blocks using Web3js

Tags: web3js, forks, chain-reorganization

Assuming there is a reorganization at block height N, the block with hash H being the forked block and H' the block that is the 'actual' one.

**1.**
Will `web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders' \[, callback\]);`([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-subscribe.html#id11)) be called twice with `blockNumber = N`, once with `hash = H` and a second time with `hash = H'`?

**2.**
Is there a way to list all reorganized blocks? My current idea is to go through all blocks (which isn't very efficient for obvious reasons) and see if `web3.eth.getBlock(n)` returns a different hash from the one I saved for the block at `n`, eventually finding that `web3.eth.getBlock(N)` returns `H'` which is different from what I have saved before (`H`).

**3.**
Is there a way to test this (1.) behavior? As the `subscribe` method listens to new blocks and I would have to wait for a reorg to happen.

I am aware of these two questions ([detect reorg](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-can-a-dapp-detect-a-fork-or-chain-reorganization-using-web3-js-or-additional), [detect orphant](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83460/detect-orphant-or-uncle-block)), but the first one talks about looking for a certain transaction and verifies if it's still valid compared to looking for any reorg-block, the second one does not include web3js.